# Retropie n64 Mario Party Issues

Tags: pi-3, retropie

I recently outfitted my Raspberry Pi with Retropie v3.8.1 and have been seeing some issues with any of the n64 Mario Party games. All of the mini-games are very playable, but the board spaces are not mapped correctly with the background map image. This makes it nearly impossible to play, especially when you need to select which direction you want to travel. I have tried all of the n64 emulators that come with Retropie. I am running on a Pi 3.

Has anyone else seen this issue? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Retropie 4.0 and use the GLideN64-hires plugin. I had the same issue when using other plugins. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get a widescreen hack to work with it though.

Comment: Nice I'll give that a try. Still running v3.8